# Checking that ftp is up and running on Windows Vista?

Tags: ftp

If you got to http://localhost you can check that you're webserver is up and running but what do you type in to check that you're ftp server is up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ftp://127.0.0.1
```

or

```
ftp://localhost
```

Comment: Ok, great thanks it was embarrassing simple, but I probably remember this for that's sake.

Comment: Or as an alternative: telnet localhost 21